# pod logs not stored in EKS nodes

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-eks, fluentd

I am trying to configure a fluend to send logs to an elasticsearch. After configuring it, I  could not see any pod logs in the elasticsearch.

While debuging what is happening, I have seen that there are no logs in the node in path `var/log/pods`:

```
cd var/logs/pods
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x. 34 root root 8192 Dec  9 12:26 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Dec  9 02:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   21 Dec  7 03:14 pod1
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root  119 Dec  7 11:17 pod2
cd pod1/containerName
ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  6 Dec  7 03:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 21 Dec  7 03:14 ..
```

But I can see the logs when executing `kubectl logs pod1`

As I have seen in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/implementing-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch/kubernetes-eks-logging.html) logs should be in this path. Do you have any idea why there are no logs stored in the node?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was happening. The problem was related with the log driver. It was configured to send the logs to journald:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' ID
journald
```

I have changed it to `json-file`. Now it is writing logs `var/log/pods`

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) there are the different logging configuration options